# Easiest way to find duplicate values in a coffeescript array

Tags: arrays, coffeescript

I am new to coffeescript. Please help me.

How do you find duplicated values in an array?

```
var arr = ['manager','manager','employee','manager',
           'director','employee','manager','operatives'];
```

In this case it should return ['manager','employee'].

Comment: `var arr = ...;` ? This is not coffeescript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
    findDuplicates = (array) ->
        keys = {}
        for value in array
            keys[value] ?= 0
            keys[value]++
        (key for key, count of keys when count > 1)

    arr = ['manager','manager','employee','manager', 'director','employee','manager','operatives']
    console.log findDuplicates(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

By using `filter`, get more easily.

```
arr = ['manager','manager','employee','manager','director','employee','manager','operatives'];

filtered = arr.filter (x, i, self) ->
  self.indexOf(x) == i && i != self.lastIndexOf(x)

console.log filtered # => ['manager', 'employee']
```